# How to pass state from class components to global state when using react hooks for global state management

Tags: reactjs

For the web app I'm building in React, I need to record audio and be able to somehow put that recorded audio in the app's global state so I can use and manipulate that recorded audio in different components of the app.

My global state is setup using React Hooks (made and managed with useReducer, createContext, useContext) and I believe Hooks only work for functional components, not class components.

So the issue I'm running up against is that every tutorial I've followed to get my browser microphone to work uses class components (like the code below), not functional components. And I'm assuming that this is for good reason because when I've tried to translate these class components into functional components, I get the error: "cannot read property 'finish' of 'undefined'"

**Are there ways to take this audio data (blobURL) and pass it to my global state?**

**Alternatively (and ideally), is there a way to use the microphone to record audio in a functional component instead of a class component?**

```
import MicRecorder from "mic-recorder-to-mp3";
import React from "react";

const Mp3Recorder = new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 });

class AudioRecorder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    this.state = {
      isRecording: false,
      isPaused: false,
      blobURL: "",
      isBlocked: false
    };
  }

  startRecording = () => {
    if (this.state.isBlocked) {
      console.log("Please give permission for the microphone to record audio.");
    } else {
      Mp3Recorder.start()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ isRecording: true });
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }
  };

  stopRecording = () => {
    this.setState({ isRecording: false });
    Mp3Recorder.stop()
      .getMp3()
      .then(async ([buffer, blob]) => {
        const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        this.setState({ 
          blobURL: blobURL,
          isRecording: false
        });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };

  checkPermissionForAudio = () => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
      navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    }
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {
        // First get ahold of the legacy getUserMedia, if present
        var getUserMedia =
          // navigator.getUserMedia ||
          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        // Some browsers just don't implement it - return a rejected promise with an error
        // to keep a consistent interface
        if (!getUserMedia) {
          return Promise.reject(
            new Error("getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser")
          );
        }

        // Otherwise, wrap the call to the old navigator.getUserMedia with a Promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
        });
      };
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(stream => {
        this.setState({ isBlocked: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ isBlocked: true });
        console.log("Please give permission for the microphone to record audio.");      
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPermissionForAudio();
  }

  render() {
    const { isRecording } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button
          onClick={this.startRecording}
          className="mr-3 add-collec-btn"
          disabled={isRecording}
        >
          Record
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={this.stopRecording}
          className="mr-3 delete-btn"
          disabled={!isRecording}
        >
          Stop
        </button>
        <audio
          ref="audioSource"
          controls="controls"
          src={this.state.blobURL || ""}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioRecorder;
```

**UPDATE:**
This is how I've set up Context in my application and how it's provided through the code. In my store folder, I have three files: Context.js, GlobalStateProvider, and useGlobalState.

**Context.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const Context = createContext({});

export default Context;
```

**GlobalStateProvider.js**

This wraps everything in my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import useGlobalState from './useGlobalState';
import Context from './Context';

const GlobalStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={useGlobalState()}>{children}</Context.Provider>
    );
}

export default GlobalStateProvider;
```

**useGlobalState.js**

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SETISRECORD':
            return {
                ...state,
                isRecording: action.payload
            }
        case 'SETISBLOCKED':
            return {
                ...state,
                isBlocked: action.payload
            }
        case 'setBlobURL':
            return {
                ...state,
                blobURL: action.payload
            }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
};

const useGlobalState = () => {
    const [globalState, globalDispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        isRecording: false,
        isBlocked: false,
        blobURL: '',
    });

    return { globalState, globalDispatch };
}

export default useGlobalState;
```

I then interface with my global state in functional components like so:

```
const functionalComponent = () => {  
    const { globalState, globalDispatch } = useContext(Context);

    return (
      [code]
    );
}
```

Comment: Class-based components can still access a React Context, though it isn't via the `useContext` React hook, it'll instead be by a `Context.Consumer`. Can you update your question to include your context code and how it is provided to your application?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the response! I've updated the question to include my context code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class-based components can still "consume" the context but the syntax is a little more involved than simply using a `useContext` React hook.

[Context.Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

For your case you would import your global state context `Context` and render the component that needs to access the context via a function child. The child component would then need consume these context values via props.

Some classed-based component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { myContext: { globalState, globalDispatch } } = this.props;
    return (
      [code]
    );
  }
}
```

Wrap and pass via props:

```
import MyContext from '../path/to/context';

...

<MyContext.Consumer>
  {myContext => <MyComponent myContext={myContext} />}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked for getting globalDispatch and globalState into the class component. The goal here is to be able to use globalDispatch({ type: 'setBlobURL', payload: blobURL }) to be able to get the recorded audio into the globalState for me to access in other areas of the app. However, whenever I use globalDispatch I get the error: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate." Any insight here?

Comment: @RayhanMemon When you use `globalDispatch` are you unconditionally invoking it? How/where are you calling it? You can add these details to your question.

Comment: you were right, I was invoking it within the render function but without a condition not thinking it would be called repeatedly. using "const { myContext: { globalState, globalDispatch } } = this.props;" within the onClick functions solves my issues. Thank you!